# Map "insert" key for ViM in RStudio to enter "insert" mode

Tags: vim, rstudio

I started using the ViM mode for text editor in RStudio (1.1.453). I can get into the "insert" mode using the 'i' key, but not using the "insert" key. I looked through the "Modify Keyboard Shortcuts", but cannot figure out the relevant option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some serious searching, it appears that there is no <kbd>Insert</kbd> key that can be mapped in Vim.

I'm hoping to be corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your search. I hope there is a solution. Overall, ViM implementation in RStudio seems minimal.